# Hive - filter different names

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, filtering, hiveql

I´ve got stucked by filtering some movie titels. My problem is that i have a lot of different movie titels for example:

```
Movies:                                       Visitors:
    Breaking Dawn Part 1+2                    100
    Breaking Dawn 1+2                         40
    Breaking Dawn 1 + 2                       30
    Dark Knight trilogy 3D                    100
    Dark Knight trilogy  3D                   40
    Dark Knight Trilogy HDF                   30
    Dark Knight Trilogy -HDF                  100
    Dark Knight trilogy_ (blank)              44
    etc. +10000
```

So there are a lot of different movie titels, which aren´t named unique and also have some whitespaces at the end. I could fixed that problem a litte, but there are already a lot of titels, which have the same meaning but are different.
At the moment is that my Query:

```
SELECT  regexp_replace(rtrim(allcinemadata.title)," - 3D | - 3D |3D |3D| 3D| - (3D) | - (3D) |(3D)"|"") 
as clearTitle
FROM default.allcinemadata
group by
regexp_replace(rtrim(allcinemadata.title)," - 3D | - 3D |3D |3D| 3D| - (3D) | - (3D) |(3D)", "")
```

I´m not sure if that is the best solution for that problem.
Hope you guys can help me! :)

Comment: can you be more specific about how you want  your data transformed.

Comment: Well I want for every title an absolut visitor value, but my biggest problem is, that the titles are named differently. So I don´t know how i could merge them. For example "Dark Knight" there are five different names (endings), but I want just the sum of all of them. So Movie = "Dark Knight"; Visitors = "314"

Comment: I´m not sure if there is a function that could look in any row and check/decide if the next row are similar to the first one. And if they are similar they should named Dark Knight or Breaking Dawn without any endings and a sum of the similar visitors

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this with a larger dataset but it works for the sample data you provided in the question. based on soundex function on movie name get the total of the views, rest of the sql is self explanatory.

```
WITH movviews
     AS (SELECT moviename,
                totalviews,
                Rank()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY Soundex(moviename)
                    ORDER BY totalviews DESC) rnk
         FROM   (SELECT moviename,
                        Sum(views)
                          OVER (
                            partition BY Soundex(moviename)
                            ORDER BY moviename) AS totalviews,
                        views
                 FROM   movieviews
                 ORDER  BY moviename)vv)
SELECT movviews.moviename,
       movviews.totalviews
FROM   movviews
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

Output

```
movviews.moviename             movviews.totalviews
Breaking Dawn Part 1+2          170
Dark Knight trilogy_ (blank)    314
Time taken: 62.257 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive (default)>
```